# How to Rotate SatelliteMenu 180° and place it on top|right of screen in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, satellite-navigation

I have tried using the .setRotation but this makes my application crash, can some let me know on how I can solve this issue below is the code

```
xml
<android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
......

menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    float distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            170, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    menu.setSatelliteDistance((int) distance);
    menu.setExpandDuration(500);
    menu.setCloseItemsOnClick(true);
    menu.setTotalSpacingDegree(90);
    menu.setMainImage(R.drawable.ic_main);
    menu.setRotation(180);
```

logcat

```
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu.setRotation
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.willapps.MainActivity.satelliteMenuconfig(MainActivity.java:194)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.willapps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 10:50:06.936: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: logcat might help you (us) to understand your crash issue. setRotation is API 11+, maybe it's your explanation, maybe not, can't tell if you don't provide the exception log.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError means i was probably right, what's your phone android version ? the method setRotation is only available for 11+ (which is 3.0). Anyway i don't think it would do what you want to achieve. I never used this lib, but i would try something with negative satellite distance. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)

Comment: its still displaying the pop up icons on the right